# Life-time error in Parallel segmented-prime-sieve in Rust

Tags: rust, parallel-processing

I am trying to make parallel a prime sieve in Rust but Rust compiler not leave of give me a lifemetime error  with the parameter `true_block`.

And data races are irrelevant because how primes are defined.

The error is:

```
    error[E0621]: explicit lifetime required in the type of `true_block`
  --> src/sieve.rs:65:22
   |
50 |     true_block: &mut Vec<bool>,
   |                 -------------- help: add explicit lifetime `'static` to the type of `true_block`: `&'static mut Vec<bool>`
...
65 |         handles.push(thread::spawn(move || {
   |                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ lifetime `'static` required
```

The code is:

```
fn extend_helper(
    primes: &Vec<usize>,
    true_block: &mut Vec<bool>,
    segment_min: usize,
    segment_len: usize,
) {
    let mut handles: Vec<thread::JoinHandle<()>> = vec![];
    let arc_primes = Arc::new(true_block);

    let segment_min = Arc::new(segment_min);
    let segment_len = Arc::new(segment_len);
    for prime in primes {
        let prime = Arc::new(prime.clone());
        let segment_min = Arc::clone(&segment_min);
        let segment_len = Arc::clone(&segment_len);
        let shared = Arc::clone(&arc_primes);

        handles.push(thread::spawn(move || {
            let tmp = smallest_multiple_of_n_geq_m(*prime, *segment_min) - *segment_min;
            for j in (tmp..*segment_len).step_by(*prime) {
                shared[j] = false;
            }
        }));
    }

    for handle in handles {
        handle.join().unwrap();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lifetime issue is with `true_block` which is a mutable reference passed into the function.  Its lifetime is only as long as the call to the function, but because you're spawning a thread, the thread *could* live past the end of the function (the compiler can't be sure).  Since it's not known how long the thread will live for, the lifetime of data passed to it must be `'static`, meaning it will live until the end of the program.

To fix this, you can use `.to_owned()` to clone the array stored in the `Arc`, which will get around the lifetime issue.  You would then need to copy the array date out of the `Arc` after joining the threads and write it back to the true_block reference.  But it's also not possible to mutate an `Arc`, which only holds an immutable reference to the value.  You need to use an `Arc<Mutex<_>>` for `arc_primes` and then you can mutate `shared` with `shared.lock().unwrap()[j] = false;` or something safer

Comment: I have tow probles with your approach:
1. Mutex is overhead because a number just need at least 1 multiple to not be prime so data races are not relevant.
2. Are some way to say to the compiler that i am sure that the function will live at most the life of that  threads?

Comment: 1. You need a mutex to safely handle runtime access to the vector contents.  The alternative is unsafe, or else you can restructure how you pass data back from the threads, which is probably a good idea anyways.  2. You can look into scoped threads, such as the crate crossbeam, which will allow you to create a thread that lives only long enough until the join that occurs in the same function, but it means introducing a new crate.  The compiler used to have a mechanism for this but it was unsound and was removed

Comment: 1. I am safe that if two write to the vector are at the same time it will no matter (in this case) so how make it unsafe?

Comment: You can use the unsafe keyword to suspend the borrow checker, but using unsafe would defeat the purpose of Rust, so I don't recommend it.  Honestly, you should look into using a different way of getting data back from your threads, since using a vec like this isn't the best way.  You could try a mapreduce style method like https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/std_misc/threads/testcase_mapreduce.html

Comment: I tried to ’unsafe {
            shared = &mut *true_block;
        }’ in the for loop but it still not allow me to make several mut references.

Comment: Did you get an error about DerefMut is not defined on Arc because you didn't remove the Arc?  Please just look at the mapreduce example

Comment: I already remove th Arc. And in the `unsafe { shared = &mut *true_block; }` the `true_block` is parameter true_block.

Comment: And the error is: error[E0499]: cannot borrow `*true_block` as mutable more than once at a time